# Not able to get lat in ol.proj.transform

Tags: coordinates, coordinate-system, markers

I'm not sure what's going on with this code, but I don't see anything wrong with it.

My alert is able to return the lon and lat exactly as I need them. However, when I pass it through ol.proj.transform and ol.geom.Point, lat is never returned.

This is my HTML:

```
<div class="query-result" data-result="Virginia, United States" data-long="-77.44674710199968" data-lat="37.548116362000485" data-bbox="-80.285748,34.709116,-74.607748,40.387116" data-latlong="-77.44674710199968,37.548116362000485">Virginia, United States</div>
```

This is my javascript:

```
$(document.body).on('click', '.query-result', function(){
    var lon = $(this).attr('data-long');
    var lat = $(this).attr('data-lat');
    alert(lon);
    alert(lat);
    var feature = new ol.Feature(
      geometry: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.transform([lon, lat], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'))      
    );
    feature.setStyle(iconStyle);
    vectorSource.addFeature(feature);
    map.addLayer(vectorLayer);   
});
```

I'm specifically plotting a point on map when someone clicks .query-result. It works when I hardcode the coords, but not when passing them through my code.

I don't understand why.

Answer (score 2):

After communicating with the OpenLayers folks, it seems that, for some reason first coord works, but the second doesn't unless you convert the string to a number. Actually, BOTH have to be a number instead of a string.

Solution:

```
 $(document.body).on('click', '.query-result', function(){
    var lon = Number($(this).attr('data-long'));
    var lat = Number($(this).attr('data-lat'));
    coords = ol.proj.transform([lon,lat], 'EPSG:4326','EPSG:3857');
    var feature = new ol.Feature(
      new ol.geom.Point(coords)  
    );
    feature.setStyle(iconStyle);
    vectorSource.addFeature(feature);
    map.addLayer(vectorLayer); 
    $('#search-results').empty();  
    $('#searchusgs').val($(this).attr('data-result'));
 });
```

Comment: please mark your answer as accepted https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/